# Get the value from the given array

Tags: arrays

I have this given array ,
How can get the value of email and status in loop .

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [brandlogo_id] => 1
            [email] => upendtu@gmail.com
            [status] => 2
            [created_time] => 2017-11-13 14:00:10
            [update_time] => 2017-11-13 14:00:10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [brandlogo_id] => 2
            [email] => upen3592@gmail.com
            [status] => 1
            [created_time] => 2017-11-13 13:58:46
            [update_time] => 2017-11-13 13:58:46
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [brandlogo_id] => 3
            [email] => ankigupta9492@gmail.com
            [status] => 1
            [created_time] => 2017-11-13 13:57:07
            [update_time] => 2017-11-13 13:57:07
        )

)
```

please let me know how can i get this value
thank you.

Comment: Is this just a text file? What language are you using?

Comment: Its in php. I got the answer by using this  foreach ($data as $value) {
          echo $value['email'] . "<br>" ;
          echo $value['status'];      }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be it any language, the method/ also will be more or less the same apart from the syntax. Search the syntax for the language you are using to parse JSON data.
Giving examples.

**For Objective - C:**

```
    NSArray *resultDataSet=[NSArray array];
    while([results next]) {
        NSString *name = [results stringForColumn:@"brand_name"];
        resultDataSet = [resultDataSet arrayByAddingObject:name ];
    }
```

**For Python :**

```
for array in data:
    print array['email']
```

**For PHP :**

```
foreach($arr as $item) { //foreach element in $array
    $stat = $item['status']; //etc
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using PHP or python (as this is an associative array) and the name of the array is "arr".
This code shall do the job.

**For PHP**

```
foreach($arr as $subarray) {
    echo $subarray["email"]." ".$subarray["status"]."<br>";
}
```

**For Python**

```
for subarray in arr:
    print subarray["email"], " ", subarray["status"]
```

It will display output similar to

```
xyz@gmail.com 2
abc@yahoo.com 3
```